# std::async: The created threads still alive even though the tasks are finished?

Tags: c++, multithreading, asynchronous, c++11, future

I'm currently using std::async in order to launch a several tasks(4) simultaneously, after the launch I wait for the task to finish using std::future objects.The problem is that when I see the system monitoring, it appears that more than 13 threads have been created and do not terminate.

Here is the piece of code:

```
System system;
std::vector<Compressor> m_compressorContainer(4);
std::vector<future<void> > m_futures(4);

while( system.isRunning() )
{

int index=0;

//launch one thread per compressor
for ( auto &compressor : m_compressorContainer )
{   
  m_futures[index++] = std::async(std::launch::any, &Compressor::process, compressor );
}

//wait for results
std::for_each( m_futures.begin(),m_futures.end(), [](std::future<void> &future){ future.get(); } );

}
```

Since I'm waiting the end of each thread, I was expecting that the number of thread will always be 4 and not 13.

No idea ?

Comment: `async` makes no promise whatsoever about what threads are used (if any) and how they're managed.

Comment: Also, why `for_each`? Just `for (auto & f : futures) f.get();`.

Comment: Well , About threads, I was expecting that, after calling future.get(), the thread will end up and will not still be alive.

Comment: About using std::for_each, I, guess it is just a matter of taste, there is no objective reason that can justify using one instead of the other in this specific case.

Comment: The "objective reason" is that `std::for_each` is a legacy crutch that C++98 introduced because there was no range-based `for` loop. The sheer difference in verbosity should speak for itself. Also, one requires a library, and the other doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

Threads, like memory, may be kept alive by the library for reuse in the future. E.g. `delete p;` isn't guaranteed to return memory to the system either.